# SQL Server Column level security - is it possible to DENY SELECTs on a column, but, have it available for use in a WHERE clause on that table?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

SQL Server 2008, 2012, 2014 Column level security - is it possible to DENY SELECTs on a column, but, have it available for use in the WHERE clause on that table?

I don't want to allow a specific role to read all email addresses, in the "EmailAddress" column, but, I do want that role to check if a particular email address exists.

ie. I don't want:
SELECT EmailAddress FROM MyTable

But, I do want:
SELECT MyTableID FROM MyTable WHERE EmailAddress = 'someone@test.com'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that.  It has to be open to selects in order for the column to be used in a where clause.

This is not exactly what your after, but maybe it can be of use to you.

[Column Level Permissions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/)

Comment: Is there a query I can use to see which columns have column-level permissions?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to create one View. In that view only give selected columns.

```
    Create View Vw_MyTable
    As
     Select MyId From MyTable
```